# Why does this regex match return a hashmap?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

I have a hashmap and I'm doing a regex against each of the keys.  Upon matching I would like to store this information into a list (not a hashmap).  Here is what I'm doing:

```
$listOfStuff = $myArray.keys | % { if($_.FullName -match 'KB[0-9]{7}') { $matches } }
```

This returns a the following:

```
Name        Value
----        ----
0           KB1234567
0           KB0123456
0           KB0012345
0           KB0001234
```

How can I get it to just return:

```
KB1234567
KB0123456
KB0012345
KB0001234
```

Comment: To answer the title, it returns a hashmap because regex supports having multiple capture groups in a single regex by using `( )`, `Name` tells you which group did the capture (`0` represents the entire regex string, the first capture group would be `1` and counting up from there.)

Answer (score 2):

one way:

```
$listOfStuff = $myArray.keys | 
               % { if($_.FullName -match 'KB[0-9]{7}') { $matches } } | 
               select -expa value
```

Comment: Having trouble with the `select expa value`

Comment: Getting `property value cannot be found`

Comment: I had a typo in my comment, the code doesn't understand what `value` is.  I tried using `$_` and that just returned my original results.

Comment: Could you post what `$listOfStuff[0].gettype()` return in you example?

Comment: Its returning `System.Array`

Comment: Heh.. It was an easy fix.  I didn't add your `| select -expa value` and all I did was change `$matches` to `$matches.values`.